# Installing Git LFS

Tags: linux, git, opensuse, yum, rpm

I'm following [this](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter7/4?fw=pt#finetuning-the-model-with-the-trainer-api) guide. When I have to run this `trainer`:

```
trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model,
    args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets,
    eval_dataset=tokenized_eval,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)
```

I get:

```
OSError: Looks like you do not have git-lfs installed, please install. You can install from https://git-lfs.github.com/. Then run `git lfs install` (you only have to do this once).
```

I have installed it from the webpage successfully, but when I run `git lfs install` I get (loosely translated):

```
git: «lfs» is not a git command. See «git --help».

The most similar command is
        log
```

I'm on an OpenSUSE Leap 15.3..

I also ran `curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash` in my terminal according to [this guide](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/INSTALLING.md), which seems successful because the last line says `The repository is setup! You can now install packages.`, but then when I run `sudo yum install git-lfs` it says `sudo: yum: command not found`.

Up!

Comment: So you have _not_ installed it successfully. I’m not familiar with openSUSE, but it may also be using the `dnf` tool instead of `yum` by now. Try `sudo dnf install git-lfs`.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. I have `script.rpm.sh` in my Downloads folder though.

Comment: Please somebody help!

Comment: Your best bet for interactive help is the [GitHub Discussions forum for the LFS project](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/discussions).